# Understanding regex behavior with Lightning Input

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, regular-expressions, lightninginput

I'm new with all the LWC topic. But for now I'm having issues with some regex.
To Begin with I have my own LWC created with a few fields some of them are type number such this one:

```
<lightning-input label="CCV" type="number" value={valueCvv} onchange={handleCvvChange} id="card-ccv" maxlength="3"></lightning-input>
```

From what I'm trying to do in this case CCV is for the input only accept numbers (0-9). But for now is accepting them but also this characters **´ + , . -**. Here is the event:

```
 handleCvvChange(event){
    this.valueCvv = event.target.value;    
    event.detail.value = event.detail.value.replace(/^([0-9])*$/,'');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the handleCvv method to this:

```
In template change `onchange` to `onkeypress`

handleCvvChange(event) {
    if (event.key.length === 1 && /\D/.test(event.key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        this.valueCvv = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

what this does is we replace all non digit character with the value you specified in the second parameter of `.replace` method and reassign it back to **valueCvv** property

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed it. But still letting me to add those characters.

Comment: Hi pablo. I updated my answer. Can you please try again

Comment: To see it in action: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/3Qr43KJ1tAi8zPo0IJw6

Comment: Thanks again for your answer!. couldn't find an example by using onkeypress thanks for it. I have found another solution. Would you add it? it works with onchange I'll mark it as solved.

handleCvvChange(event){        
        event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');   
    }